# A sequence of bounded $C^1$ functions whose derivatives are unbounded.

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, functions, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

What is an example of a sequence of functions, $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subset C^1([a,b])$, which are bounded in $C^1([a,b])$ under $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ but are such that their first derivatives $\|f'_n\|_{\infty}\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$?

There are many examples on this site for a single function, but I am looking for an intance when we have a sequence of functions. Are there any particularly simple instances which can be provided to demonstrate the above point?

Comment: $f_n(x)=\sin(nx)$?

Comment: Indeed particularly simple! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f_n(x)=\sin(nx)$ as per the comment of Mindlack.

The sequence $(\sin(nx))_{n=1}^\infty\subset C^1([a,b])$ is bounded since for all $n\in\mathbb N$ one has that $\|\sin(nx)\|_{\infty}=1$.

Additionally, for each $n\in\mathbb N$ we have that $f_n'(x)=n\cos(nx)$. Then,
$$\|f_n'\|_\infty=\|n\cos(nx)\|_\infty=|n|\|\cos(nx)\|_\infty= n,$$
which implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n'\|_\infty=\infty$. Thus, the derivatives of $(\sin(nx))_{n=1}^\infty\subset C^1([a,b])$ are unbounded.

Comment: Could you at least type up a little bit more? Otherwise you leave people no choice but to vote-to-delete this "answer".